# Using scan_parquet and scan_pyarrow_dataset on S3 loads entire dataset into memory

Tags: python, amazon-s3, parquet, python-polars, pyarrow

I have a large, partitioned, parquet dataset that does not fit into memory and is stored in an S3 location. A piece of of processing code is meant to process a subset of this data by performing a join on another dataset that selects a subset of the rows of the large dataset.

I was hoping to use Polars' lazy loading and streaming join functionality to avoid having to load the large dataset into memory and I was hoping to do this directly from S3.

If I use scan_parquet, or scan_pyarrow_dataset on a local parquet file, I can see in the query play that Polars performs a streaming join, but if I change the location of the file to an S3 location, this does not work and Polars appears to first load the entire file into memory before performing the join.

This blogpost describes something very similar to what I'm trying and suggests that it should work: https://www.confessionsofadataguy.com/polars-vs-pandas-inside-an-aws-lambda/

Below is an example that tests three different methods:

1. a scanned parquet file a local file
2. a parquet scan from an S3 location
3. a streaming join on a scanned pyarrow dataset from an S3 location.

```
import s3fs
import polars as pl
import pyarrow.dataset as ds

S3_BUCKET = "bucket-with-write-access"
S3_KEY = "key"

df_a = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": ["a", "a", "a", "a", "c"],
        "b": ["b", "b", "b", "b", "d"]
    }
)
df_b = pl.DataFrame({"a": ["c"]}).lazy()

# Write to local file and to S3
local_path = 'a.parquet'
s3_path = f"s3://{S3_BUCKET}/{S3_KEY}"

fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem()

# First two test cases: use scan_parquet on either a local file
# or an S3 file
for path in [local_path, s3_path]:
    if path.startswith('s3://'):
        open_func = fs.open
    else:
        open_func = open
    with open_func(path, 'wb') as f:
        df_a.write_parquet(f)
    lazy_df = pl.scan_parquet(path)
 
    print(lazy_df.join(df_b, on='a').explain(streaming=True))

# Third test case: use scan_pyarrow_dataset on an S3 dataset
dataset = ds.dataset(
    [s3_path],
    filesystem=fs,
    format="parquet",
)
lazy_df = pl.scan_pyarrow_dataset(dataset)
print(lazy_df.join(df_b, on='a').explain(streaming=True))
```

Test case 1 yields the following (streaming join) query plan as expected:

```
--- PIPELINE
INNER JOIN:
LEFT PLAN ON: [col("a")]

    PARQUET SCAN a.parquet
    PROJECT */2 COLUMNS
RIGHT PLAN ON: [col("a")]
  DF ["a"]; PROJECT */1 COLUMNS; SELECTION: "None"
END INNER JOIN  --- END PIPELINE
```

However, test case 2 and 3 yield the following unexpected query plan that does not push down the join predicate

```
--- PIPELINE
INNER JOIN:
LEFT PLAN ON: [col("a")]

    PYTHON SCAN 
    PROJECT */2 COLUMNS
RIGHT PLAN ON: [col("a")]
  DF ["a"]; PROJECT */1 COLUMNS; SELECTION: "None"
END INNER JOIN
```

EDIT:

It seems that predicate pushdown is not supported for scan_parquet from S3 https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/3626

EDIT:

The MWE code only works with Polars 0.18.3 or lower due to a regression on `scan_parquet` from S3 locations. See https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/10008

Comment: On Polars' GitHub there are some issues around scanning files in the cloud and there is no (official) solution. Check e.g. https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/10008

Comment: Interesting to read that scan_parquet on S3 files is not officially supported.

I did come across this particular issue. Indeed scan_parquet does not work for s3 files on polars 0.18.x. However scan_pyarrow_dataset works with S3 files both on the latest and on older versions of polars and using this method I still don't get streaming join behavior in the polars versions I tried.

Comment: As an unrelated question, why are you converting to pandas to save a parquet?

Comment: @DeanMacGregor convenience or laziness. Pandas' `to_parquet` accepts S3 destinations as its argument whereas Polars' `write_parqet` requires a file object. I've edited the example to eliminate the pandas dependency