# How to limit memory usage while scanning parquet from S3 and join using Polars?

Tags: python, python-polars, pyarrow

As a follow-up question to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76770890/using-scan-parquet-and-scan-pyarrow-dataset-on-s3-loads-entire-dataset-into-memo), I would like to find a way to limit the memory usage when scanning, filtering and joining a large dataframe saved in S3 cloud, with a tiny local dataframe.

Suppose my code looks like the following:

```
import pyarrow.dataset as ds
import polars as pl
import s3fs

# S3 credentials
secret = ...
key = ...
endpoint_url = ...

# some tiny dataframe
sellers_df = pl.DataFrame({'seller_id': ['0332649223', '0192491683', '0336435426']})

# scan, filter and join with huge dataframe on S3
fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem(endpoint_url=endpoint_url, key=key, secret=secret)
dataset = ds.dataset(f'{s3_bucket}/benchmark_dt/dt_partitions', filesystem=fs, partitioning='hive')
    scan_df = pl.scan_pyarrow_dataset(dataset) \
        .filter(pl.col('dt') >= '2023-05-17') \
        .filter(pl.col('dt') <= '2023-10-18') \
        .join(sellers_df.lazy(), on='seller_id', how='inner').collect()
```

And my parquet files layout, looks like the following:

```
-- dt_partitions
    -- dt=2023-06-09
        -- data.parquet
    -- dt=2023-06-10
            -- data.parquet
    -- dt=2023-06-11
        -- data.parquet
    -- dt=2023-06-12
        -- data.parquet
    ...
```

When running the code I notice that Polars first loads the entire dataset to the memory, according to the given dates, and **after** performs the join.
This causes me severe memory problems.

Is there any way to perform the join in pre-defined batches/streaming to save memory?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

This is the explain plan (you can see no streaming applied):

```
INNER JOIN:
LEFT PLAN ON: [col("seller_id")]

    PYTHON SCAN 
    PROJECT */3 COLUMNS
    SELECTION: ((pa.compute.field('dt') >= '2023-10-17') & (pa.compute.field('dt') <= '2023-10-18'))
RIGHT PLAN ON: [col("seller_id")]
  DF ["seller_id"]; PROJECT */1 COLUMNS; SELECTION: "None"
END INNER JOIN
INNER JOIN:
LEFT PLAN ON: [col("seller_id")]
```

However, when using `is_in`:

```
PYTHON SCAN 
  PROJECT */3 COLUMNS
  SELECTION: ((pa.compute.field('seller_id')).isin(["0332649223","0192491683","0336435426","3628932648","5241104373","1414317462","4028203396","6445502649","1131069079","9027417785","6509736571","9214134975","7722199293","1617136891","8786329949","8260764409","5103636478","3444202168","9066806312","3961998994","7345385102","2756955097","7038039666","0148664533","5120870693","8843132164","6424549457","8242686761","3148647530","8329075741","0803877447","2228154163","8661602117","2544985488","3241983296","4756084729","5317176976","0658022895","3802149808","2368104663","0835399702","0806598632","9753553141","3473629988","1145080603","5731199445","7622500016","4980968502","6713967792","8469333969"]) & ((pa.compute.field('dt') >= '2023-10-17') & (pa.compute.field('dt') <= '2023-10-18')))
```

Followed @Dean MacGregor answer, added `os.environ['AWS_ALLOW_HTTP'] = 'true'` and it worked:

```
--- STREAMING
INNER JOIN:
LEFT PLAN ON: [col("seller_id")]

    Parquet SCAN s3://test-bucket/benchmark_dt/dt_partitions/dt=2023-10-17/part-0.parquet
    PROJECT */3 COLUMNS
RIGHT PLAN ON: [col("seller_id")]
  DF ["seller_id"]; PROJECT */1 COLUMNS; SELECTION: "None"
END INNER JOIN  --- END STREAMING
```

Comment: what does `print(pl.scan_pyarrow_dataset(dataset) \
        .filter(pl.col('dt') >= '2023-05-17') \
        .filter(pl.col('dt') <= '2023-10-18') \
        .join(sellers_df.lazy(), on='seller_id', how='inner').explain())` say?

Comment: How about doing `.filter(pl.col('seller_id' in ['0332649223', '0192491683', '0336435426'])`

Comment: @DeanMacGregor it says "python scan" instead of "parquet scan", i will post explain plan tommorow

Comment: @0x26res i will check and update here

Comment: @0x26res polars isn't 100% at mapping and pushing its filters to pyarrow datasets. My early guess is to consolidate the their 2 filters into one `.filter((pl.col('dt') >= '2023-05-17') & (pl.col('dt') <= '2023-10-18'))` and that the join is fine. If not that then maybe something weird like `.filter(pl.col('dt').is_in(pl.select(pl.date_range(pl.date(2023,5,17),pl.date(2023,10,18),'1d').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))['date'])` and if not that then just doing the filtering in pyarrow before handing off to polars.

Comment: how about using `allow_pyarrow_filter` in `scan_pyarrow_dataset` https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.scan_pyarrow_dataset.html

Comment: @DeanMacGregor actually the dt filters are pushed down to pyarrow just fine, the problem is the join is not happaning while fetching the data, but rather after all data is loaded to memory.

Comment: @0x26res it's the default value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

polars doesn't (know how to) do predicate pushdown to the pa dataset. The development efforts are to bolster its own cloud hive reading so perhaps give that a try?

The syntax for using it is a bit different than pyarrow.

It should look roughly like this with possible nuance for how to enter your auth info.

```
import polars as pl

scan_df = pl.scan_parquet(f's3://{s3_bucket}/benchmark_dt/dt_partitions/**/*.parquet', 
                  storage_options={'access_key_id':key,
                                   'secret_access_key':secret}
)
```

Note the difference in syntax: The path needs the "s3://" prefix and you have to use globbing patterns for the hive structure. For the auth, use the `storage_options` parameter with a dictionary with key values supported by [object store](https://docs.rs/object_store/0.7.0/object_store/aws/enum.AmazonS3ConfigKey.html). It doesn't rely on, or utilize, `fsspec`/`s3fs` as pyarrow does.

From there you can do

```
scan_df.filter(pl.col('dt') >= '2023-05-17') \
        .filter(pl.col('dt') <= '2023-10-18') \
        .join(sellers_df.lazy(), on='seller_id', how='inner').collect()
```

However, for predicate_pushdown to work, since your hive doesn't partition by `seller_id`, your underlying parquet files would need to have row_groups that are separated by `seller_id` and statistics that denote that separation.

Even without predicate pushdown, it is still possible to stream the data but you need to change `collect()` to `collect(streaming=True)`.

If you need to access a local/custom S3 endpoint then set `os.environ['AWS_ALLOW_HTTP'] = 'true'` to tell Object Store to connect to a non AWS url. [Here](https://docs.rs/object_store/latest/object_store/aws/struct.AmazonS3Builder.html#method.from_env) are more environment variables that it will look for/at.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer - I indeed noticed the scan_parquet option, but I was certain private S3 cloud (no AWS) is not supported, is it?

Comment: I tried now with custom S3 cloud endpoint, and got source:builder error URL scheme is not allowed.

Comment: I've never used custom s3 myself but I think if you include in the `storage_options` dict a key called `endpoint_url` then that's where you'd put that. See the linked object store doc.

Comment: Thats what I tried, and got the error "source:builder error for url (<the url>): URL scheme is not allowed"

Comment: Added os.environ['AWS_ALLOW_HTTP'] = 'true' and it worked! Please add it to your answer, and I will accept.

Comment: awesome, glad it worked